# Capitalize the first and last letter of three letter words in a string

Tags: matlab

I am trying to capitalize the first and last letter of only the three letter words in a string. So far, I have tried

```
spaces = strfind(str, ' ');
spaces = [0 spaces]; 
lw = diff(spaces); 
lw3 = find(lw ==4); 
a3 = lw-1; 
b3 = spaces(a3+1); 
b4 = b3 + 2 ; 
str(b3) = upper(str(b3)); 
str(b4) = upper(str(b4);
```

we had to find where the 3 letter words were first so that is what the first 4 lines of code are and then the others are trying to get it so that it will find where the first and last letters are and then capitalize them?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Wouldn't the location of the first letter of each word in `str` to be capitalized be `spaces(lw3)+1`?

Comment: I'd recommend [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and not obfuscating your own variable names. You don't gain anything from short variable names, use something meaningful.

Answer (score 5):

I would use regular expressions to identity the 3-letter words and then use `regexprep` combined with an anonymous function to perform the case-conversion.

```
str = 'abcd efg hijk lmn';

% Custom function to capitalize the first and last letter of a word
f = @(x)[upper(x(1)), x(2:end-1), upper(x(end))];

% This will match 3-letter words and apply function f to them
out = regexprep(str, '\<\w{3}\>', '${f($0)}')

%   abcd EfG hijk LmN
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are definitely the way to go. I am going to suggest a slightly different route, and that is to return the indices using the `tokenExtents` flag for `regexpi`:

```
str = 'abcd efg hijk lmn';

% Tokenize the words and return the first and last index of each
idx = regexpi(str, '(\<w{3}\>)', 'tokenExtents');

% Convert those indices to upper case
str([idx{:}]) = upper(str([idx{:}]));
```

Using the [matlab ipusum](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43428-matlab-ipsum) function from the File Exchange, I generated a 1000 paragraph random text string with mean word length 4 +/- 2.

```
str = lower(matlab_ipsum('WordLength', 4, 'Paragraphs', 1000));
```

The result was a 177,575 character string with 5,531 3-letter words. I used `timeit` to check the execution time of using `regexprep` and `regexpi` with `tokenExtents`. Using `regexpi` is an order of magnitude faster:

```
regexpi = 0.013979s
regexprep = 0.14401s
```